# Applying a haskell function to a .txt file in ghc?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've currently wrote a program to use on a .txt file but whenever i try to run it i get the error:

> cat quux.txt | ./wordCount

```
<interactive>:1:14: parse error on input `|'
```

Am i typing in my code wrong to work it on the ghc or?

Comment: What is rotate and how did you get it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use shell syntax in ghci. You should type the command into the shell instead.

Answer (score 2):

In ghci you can do

```
 :!<shell command>
```

To execute a command in the shell e.g.

```
Prelude> :!pwd
/home/me
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be thinking GHCi is a shell, it isn't.  There is no piping and no `cat` in GHCi.

Once you compile your program just do what you showed in a bash shell:

```
$ cat rotate.hs | ./rotate

ainm = od
c -< etContentsg
etl sl = inesl c
sw = apm ordsw sl
sr = apm map( ot)r sw
utStrLnp $ nlinesu $ apm nwordsu sr

otr w = ropd 1 w ++ aket 1 w
```

Comment: You might want to accept his answer if this solves the problem :)